# Excel Cell Selection

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble figuring out how to select a certain value from a column so I can move it over. In my example, I'm looking to select all the 0's in a column and then drop those cells over to a different column. How is this possible? I am running Mac Excel 2011 or 2016. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Surely you have use `VBA` macro to achieve that.